# How to test a component that does not handle a rejected promise with `wait` from the react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Typical online shopping store. I am trying to test a scenario where an AJAX request fails when the user tries to place an order. 
The user can also opt-in for a subscription service but the request for this subscription should only happen if the order placement was successful.

To test this failing scenario I use a Promise rejection but the uncaught error bubbles up and causes the test to fail.

Does anyone have an idea how I can test this, preferably without adding a `catch` to the chaining in the `onSubmit` method of the `Confirmation` component? Does **Jest** or `wait` from **react-testing-library** provide alternatives methods to test this scenario?

I understand that Jest provides [.rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects) but I am not able to figure out how I should restructure my test to make it work with `wait`.

The Component:

```js
class Confirmation extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() {
    const { createOrder, items, subscribeUser, userId } = this.props;
    createOrder({ items })
      .then(() => subscribeUser(userId));
      // no catch here because I use an error boundary component 
      // at the the top level of the App's component tree 
      // to catch and log all errors to a logging service
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="submit" 
          onClick={this.onSubmit} 
          value="Confirm Order"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The Test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  render,
  fireEvent,
  wait
} from 'react-testing-library'

import Confirmation from './Confirmation'

describe('Confirmation', () => {

  it("should not subscribe when the user's order creation fails", () => {
    const props = {
      userId: 12345,
      items: [{
        id: 121,
        qty: 1
      }, {
        id: 122,
        qty: 2
      }],
      createOrder: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject("Order creation failure")),
      subscribeUser: jest.fn(() => {})
    };

    const {
      container
    } = render( 
      <Confirmation { ...props } />
    );

    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector("#confirm-order"));

    return wait(() => {
      expect(props.createOrder).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        items: props.items
      });
      expect(props.subscribeUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

*Please note that the snippets above are not executable - in reality, the component is a bit more complex than the example above but I have tried to simplify it as much as possible without misrepresenting the problem.*

**Edit**

Wrapping `<Confirmation/>` in another component with an error boundary does not seem to be working either. The error still bubbles up the component tree to fail the test:

[image: Jest failure]

Comment: No idea how jest works, but you can .catch() the error and rethrow it to make it bubble up to error logging as well if that would help with solving the issue.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks but I tried this and it didn't work. Do you mean doing this `.catch(error => { throw error; })` - isn't this the same as not handling the error? Or perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: That's what I meant, but it's not 100% the same, the stack traces might be different.

Comment: If you go by the principle of `react-testing-library`-_The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you._- I guess you should be testing this component along with the error boundary component which should be handling the error and showing it to the user in the DOM somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small component that catches errors and render that one too:

```
const onError = jest.fn()
class Catcher extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    onError(error, info)
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

const { container } = render(
  <Catcher>
    <Confirmation { ...props } />
  </Catcher>
);

// After
expect(onError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

Comment: Thanks but this was the first thing I tried and it did not work. The error still bubbles up to fail the test. Not sure why.

Comment: I guess it's because the kind of error you're firing is not catched by the error boundary. I think your best option is to test the component that would catch the error rather than its child